# Force Flutter navigator to reload state when popping

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have one `StatefulWidget` in Flutter with button, which navigates me to another `StatefulWidget` using `Navigator.push()`. On second widget I'm changing  global state (some user preferences). When I get back from second widget to first, using `Navigator.pop()` the first widget is in old state, but I want to force it's reload. Any idea how to do this? I have one idea but it looks ugly:

1. pop to remove second widget (current one)
2. pop again to remove first widget (previous one)
3. push first widget (it should force redraw)

Comment: No answer, just a general comment: in my case, what brought me here looking for this would be solved with just having a sync method for shared_preferences where I'm guaranteed to get back an updated pref I wrote just a moment ago in another page. :\ Even using .then(...) isn't always getting me the pending-write updated data.

Comment: Just returned a value from the new page on pop, solved my issue. Refer https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Answer (score 157, accepted):

There's a couple of things you could do here. @Mahi's answer while correct could be a little more succinct and actually use push rather than showDialog as the OP was asking about. This is an example that uses `Navigator.push`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text('back'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new FirstPageState();
}

class FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

  Color color = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: color,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("next"),
            onPressed: () async {
              final value = await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                ),
              );
              setState(() {
                color = color == Colors.white ? Colors.grey : Colors.white;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        builder: (context, child) => SafeArea(child: child),
        home: FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
```

However, there's another way to do this that might fit your use-case well. If you're using the `global` as something that affects the build of your first page, you could use an [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) to define your global user preferences, and each time they are changed your FirstPage will rebuild. This even works within a stateless widget as shown below (but should work in a stateful widget as well).

An example of inheritedWidget in flutter is the app's Theme, although they define it within a widget instead of having it directly building as I have here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ColorDefinition.of(context).toggleColor();
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: new Text("back"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorDefinition extends InheritedWidget {
  ColorDefinition({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
  }): super(key: key, child: child);

  Color color = Colors.white;

  static ColorDefinition of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ColorDefinition);
  }

  void toggleColor() {
    color = color == Colors.white ? Colors.grey : Colors.white;
    print("color set to $color");
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ColorDefinition oldWidget) =>
      color != oldWidget.color;
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var color = ColorDefinition.of(context).color;

    return new Container(
      color: color,
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("next"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        builder: (context, child) => new SafeArea(
              child: new ColorDefinition(child: child),
            ),
        home: new FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
```

If you use inherited widget you don't have to worry about watching for the pop of the page you pushed, which will work for basic use-cases but may end up having problems in a more complex scenario.

Comment: Excellent, the first case worked for me perfectly (the second one is perfect for a more complex situation). Using OnWillPopUp from the second page wasn't clear to me; and didn't even work at all.

Comment: Hey, what if I want to update my list item. Let's say my 1st page contains list items and second page contains item detail. I am updating value of item and I want it updated back at list items. How to achieve that?

Comment: @AanalMehta I can give you a quick recommendation - either have a backend store (i.e. sqflite table or in-memory list) that is used from both the pages, and in the .then you could then force your widget to refresh somehow (I personally have used an incrementing counter that I change in setState before - it's not the cleanest solution but it works)... Or, you could pass the changes back to the original page in the .then function, make the modifications to your list, and then rebuild (but note that making changes to a list doesn't trigger a refresh, so once again use incrementing counter).

Comment: @AanalMehta But if that doesn't help, I'd recommend you look for some other answers that may be more relevant (I'm fairly sure I've seen a few about lists etc), or ask a new question.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Actually I tried the above one solution. I applied the chan ges in .then but it won't get reflected. I guess now I have only one option to use providers. Anyway, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @AanalMehta did you use a counter like I recommended? Modifying a list won't trigger a rebuild as flutter does comparisons like (list == list), and if you've modified the list that will report as true. You can either copy the list into a new list each time you make a change (which isn't as bad as it sounds really) or use a secondary piece of information that changes like the incrementing counter. But if you still do end up running into trouble open a question and someone will try to help =)

Comment: Sir can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159175/connectionstate-always-waiting

Comment: Great answer! Second option is a really good solution if a user can navigate to a view in different ways (actions, back button, tabs or menus). BWT, inheritFromWidgetOfExactType is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The second case suits my work and I'm trying to use it BUT I'm again facing the same problem which is The widget tree in the `FirstPage` is not rebuilding when coming back from `SecondPage`, in case that `ColorDefinition` Class is doing fine. So do you think that there is a way to rebuild the widget tree after data changed in `SecondPage`? Something like adding conditions or something like that?  any ways hasn't Flutter yet add a feature to rebuild the widget tree after popping since this question was asked? Any link would be appreciated too. Thanks in advance <3

Comment: @Taba without context it's a little difficult to tell exactly what the issue is that you're having. It might be worth asking a new question. That being said, have you used setState(() => ....) in the callback? That's normally how you'd rebuild the widget tree. Note that changing an object (i.e. adding to a list) won't actually trigger rebuild, in that case the easiest thing to do is add a change counting integer.

Comment: FIrst one works for me like a champ. Thanks for this answer

Comment: how to do the same if my second page is a stateless widget?

Comment: In the ```ColorDefinition``` shouldn't the variables be final? I thought that ```InheritedWidget``` is immutable

Comment: @Panagiss that's probably recommended nowadays, but this question & answer are from 2018, well before immutable classes were part of dart or the recommended usage.

Comment: My Riverpod level is still very limited, but if I'm not mistaken, we could also solve this problem using Riverpod providers, no?

Comment: @AlexandreCavalcante yeah for sure - or getX, or any number of other state management tools.

Comment: The first option raises an error in any scenario: Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose():... I even tried to call push with maintainState like    Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage(),maintainState: true), but the error persists

Answer (score 98):

#### Short answer:

Use this in 1st page:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/page2').then((_) => setState(() {}));
```

and this in 2nd page:

```dart
Navigator.pop(context);
```

---

There are 2 things, passing data from

- #### 1st Page to 2nd

  Use this in 1st page

  ```
    // sending "Foo" from 1st
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2("Foo")));
  ```

  Use this in 2nd page.

  ```
    class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
      final String string;

      Page2(this.string); // receiving "Foo" in 2nd

      ...
    }
  ```

---

- #### 2nd Page to 1st

  Use this in 2nd page

  ```
    // sending "Bar" from 2nd
    Navigator.pop(context, "Bar");
  ```

  Use this in 1st page, it is the same which was used earlier but with little modification.

  ```
    // receiving "Bar" in 1st
    String received = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2("Foo")));
  ```

Comment: How can I reload route A  when popping from route C using Navigator.popUntil method.

Comment: @VinothVino There is no direct way of doing that just yet, you need to do some sort of workaround.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad in activity TabBar to call the second tab from the dialog submit button click from Navigator.pushreplacement to redirect to the second tab.

Comment: don't understand when to call pop?

Comment: @alex You call `Navigator.pop(...)` from second screen - the screen from where you want to come back and return the result.

Answer (score 46):

For me this seems to work:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/myRoute").then((value) => setState(() {}));
```

Then simply call `Navigator.pop()` in the child.

Comment: this only works once, second time you go back to same route make change and pop doesn't refresh

Comment: I have not noticed this behavior, but also have not worked with flutter since 1 year. Happy to hear if others also observed this!

Answer (score 26):

The **Easy Trick** is to use the **Navigator.pushReplacement** method

**Page 1**

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Page2(),
  ),
);
```

**Page 2**

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Page1(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This way you are losing the navigator stack. What about poping the screen with the back button?

Answer (score 18):

Simply add `.then((value) { setState(() {});})` after Navigator.push on page1() just like below:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2())).then((value) { setState(() {});})
```

Now when you use `Navigator.pop(context)` from page2 your page1 rebuild itself

Answer (score 15):

```
onTapFunction(BuildContext context) async {
    final reLoadPage = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IdDetailsScreen()),
    );

    if (reLoadPage) {
        setState(() {});
    }
}
```

Now while doing `Navigator.pop` from second page to come back to first page just return some value which in my case is of `bool` type

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed because if I used `.then`  the return type would be  `bool` so I would not be able to call `setState`

Answer (score 12):

You can use pushReplacement and specify the new Route

Comment: But you are losing the navigator stack. What if you pop the screen using the android back button?

Comment: Even pushreplacement wont rebuild context and state if it has been loaded before I guess

Answer (score 11):

my solution went by adding a function parameter on SecondPage, then received the reloading function which is being done from FirstPage, then executed the function before the Navigator.pop(context) line.

FirstPage

```
refresh() {
setState(() {
//all the reload processes
});
}
```

then on pushing to the next page...

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage(refresh)),);
```

SecondPage

```
final Function refresh;
SecondPage(this.refresh); //constructor
```

then on before the navigator pop line,

```
widget.refresh(); // just refresh() if its statelesswidget
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Everything that needs to be reloaded from the previous page should be updated after the pop.

Answer (score 11):

This work really good, i got from this doc from flutter page: [flutter doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

I defined the method to control navigation from first page.

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddDirectionPage()),
    );

    //below you can get your result and update the view with setState
    //changing the value if you want, i just wanted know if i have to  
    //update, and if is true, reload state

    if (result) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

So, i call it in a action method from a inkwell, but can be called also from a button:

```
onTap: () {
   _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
},
```

And finally in the second page, to return something (i returned a bool, you can return whatever you want):

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.pop(context, true);
}
```

Comment: You can even just `await Navigator....` and omit a result value in pop.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue.

Please try this out:

In the First Page:

`Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => SecondPage()), ).then((value) => setState(() {}));`

After you pop back from SecondPage() to FirstPage() the "then" statement will run and refresh the page.

Comment: simple and elegant

Comment: easy to implement... great thanks

Answer (score 6):

Put this where you're pushing to second screen (inside an async function)

```dart
Function f;
f= await Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'ScreenName');
f();
```

Put this where you are popping

```dart
Navigator.pop(context, () {
 setState(() {});
});
```

The `setState` is called inside the `pop` closure to update the data.

Comment: Where exactly do you pass `setState` as an argument? You are basically calling `setState`inside a closure. Not passing it as an argument.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. I basically wanted a completion handler for `Navigator.pop`.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass back a `dynamic result` when you are popping the context and then call the `setState((){})` when the value is `true` otherwise just leave the state as it is.

I have pasted some code snippets for your reference.

```
handleClear() async {
    try {
      var delete = await deleteLoanWarning(
        context,
        'Clear Notifications?',
        'Are you sure you want to clear notifications. This action cannot be undone',
      );
      if (delete.toString() == 'true') {
        //call setState here to rebuild your state.

      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('error clearing notifications' + error.toString());
             }
  }



Future<bool> deleteLoanWarning(BuildContext context, String title, String msg) async {

  return await showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(
            title,
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: fontWeight, color: CustomColors.continueButton),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          content: new Text(
            msg,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              decoration: boxDecoration(),
              child: new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text('NO',),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              decoration: boxDecoration(),
              child: new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text('YES', ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ??
      false;
}
```

Regards,
Mahi

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do the second part.
First is just simply `Navigator.pop(context, true)` , right? But how I can obtain this `true` value? Using `BuildContext`?

Comment: Not working for me. I've used the result from push, called setState and got `setState() called after dispose(): 
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. ....`

Comment: hmm, this is interesting did you use `if(!mounted) return;` before every call to `setState((){});` this way you can avoid updating the disposed widgets or widgets that are no longer active.

Comment: No error but also it is not working as I predicted ;)

Comment: I have the same issue as @bartektartanus. If I add if !mounted before setState, my state will never be set. It seems simple but I have not figured it out after a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Needed to force rebuild of one of my stateless widgets. Did't want to use stateful. Came up with this solution:

```dart
await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(...);
ModalRoute.of(enclosingWidgetContext);
```

Note that context and enclosingWidgetContext could be the same or different contexts. If, for example, you push from inside StreamBuilder, they would be different.

We don't do anything here with ModalRoute. The act of subscribing alone is enough to force rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an alert dialog then you can use a Future that completes when the dialog is dismissed. After the completion of the future you can force widget to reload the state.

**First page**

```
onPressed: () async {
    await showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                 ....
            );
       }
    );
    setState(() {});
}
```

**In Alert dialog**

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

In flutter 2.5.2 this is worked for me also it works for updating a list

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondPage()))
    .then((value) => setState(() {}));
```

then in the second page I just code this

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

I have a `ListView` in fist page which is display a `list[]` data, the second page was updating the data for my `list[]` so the above code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This simple code worked for me to go to the root and reload the state:

```
    ...
    onPressed: () {
         Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', ModalRoute.withName('/'));
                },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you should make the widget watch the state. You need state management for this.

My method is based on Provider explained in [Flutter Architecture Samples](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/tree/master/change_notifier_provider) as well as [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). Please refer to them for more concise explanation but more or less the steps are :

- Define your state model with states that the widget needs to observe.

You could have multiple states say `data` and `isLoading`, to wait for some API process. The model itself extends `ChangeNotifier`.

- Wrap the widgets that depend on those states with watcher class.

This could be `Consumer` or `Selector`.

- When you need to "reload", you basically update those states and broadcast the changes.

For state model the class would look more or less as follows. Pay attention to `notifyListeners` which broadcasts the changes.

```
class DataState extends ChangeNotifier{

  bool isLoading;
  
  Data data;

  Future loadData(){
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    service.get().then((newData){
      isLoading = false;
      data = newData;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
  
}
```

Now for the widget. This is going to be very much a skeleton code.

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(

  create: (_) => DataState()..loadData(),
      
  child: ...{
    Selector<DataState, bool>(

        selector: (context, model) => model.isLoading,

        builder: (context, isLoading, _) {
          if (isLoading) {
            return ProgressBar;
          }

          return Container(

              child: Consumer<DataState>(builder: (context, dataState, child) {

                 return WidgetData(...);

              }
          ));
        },
      ),
  }
);
```

Instance of the state model is provided by ChangeNotifierProvider. Selector and Consumer watch the states, each for `isLoading` and `data` respectively. There is [not much difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774301/when-to-use-provider-ofx-vs-consumerx-in-flutter) but personally how you use them would depend on what their builders provide. Consumer provides access to the state model so calling `loadData` is simpler for any widgets directly underneath it.

If not then you can use `Provider.of`. If we'd like to refresh the page upon return from the second screen then we can do something like this:

```
await Navigator.push(context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) {
     return Screen2();
));

Provider.of<DataState>(context, listen: false).loadData();
```

Answer (score 1):

For me worked:

```
...
onPressed: (){pushUpdate('/somePageName');}
...

pushUpdate (string pageName) async {      //in the same class
  await pushPage(context, pageName);
  setState(() {});
}


//---------------------------------------------
//general sub
pushPage (context, namePage) async {
  await Navigator.pushNamed(context, namePage);
}
```

In this case doesn't matter how you pop (with button in UI or "back" in android) the update will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply use "then" after you push, when navigator pops back it will fire setState and the view will refresh.

`Navigator.push(blabla...).then((value) => setState(() {}))`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Push to second screen
 await Navigator.push(
   context,
   CupertinoPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),
   ),
 );

// Call build method to update any changes
setState(() {});
```

Comment: Not at all a good solution, since ``` Navigator.push``` would add the current page to the history and in the case of popping the context again, (user goes back home for example) it would take you to the same page again.

Answer (score 0):

Use setstate in your navigation push code.

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourPage())).then((value) {
  setState(() {
    // refresh state
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code goes to the root and reloads the state even without setState:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()),  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,);   //// this MainPage is your page to refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Another stupid but effective solution would be to create inside the first widget of a widget tree a function that all it does is call the setState() method:

```
class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> { 

    reBuild() {
      setState(() {});
    }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Pass it down to as many widgets as you want:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SecondWidget(
   reBuild,
  );
}
```

Store it as a final variable of type Function:

```
class SecondWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function buildFunction;

  const SecondWidget(this.buildFunction, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And then, once you're done, you call the function so that it will rebuild the initial widget:

```
await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
        ThirdWidget.routeName,
      ).then((value) => buildFunction());
```

This helped me in a more complex situation compared to then ones I saw in other answers, so I hope this will be helpful to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid too much flickering and prevent messing up with the routes, it can be chosen to just rebuild the current context. However this does neither do popping nor pushing, it is a refresh of the current context only - and it might not be sufficient in regards to the topic of this thread.

```
  void refresh() {
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).build(context);
    }
  }
```

The guard for mounted is included in case any async calls are made to make sure that the context is mounted and ready prior to the refresh.