# Is SingleLiveEvent actually part of the Android Architecture Components Library?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have been using the `SingleLiveData` class which can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java).  My questions are:

1. Is `SingleLiveData` is actually part of the Android Architecture Components?
2. Is it a good idea to use it?

Comment: You can read this https://medium.com/google-developers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at [Live data and its Parent/Children inheritance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) there is no such thing as SingleLiveData. Reading link provided by @Raghu, I find statement:

> The [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) class was created for a sample as a solution that worked for that particular scenario. It is a LiveData that will only send an update once.

So to answer your questions:

> Is SingleLiveData is actually part of the Android Architecture Components?

No, it is not!

> Is it a good idea to use it?

This depends on many factors. Since I haven't used it I will give general idea. Using classes that you find in demo app or other way might not be guaranteed to be updated or bug-fixed. So if you understand the class so well that you can fix any bug you might find, and if it fits your need, then use it.

But generally I would avoid that if I can find something that is well maintained and does the same job.

Since from skimming the article I get impression he is trying to make some sort of observer pattern, I will suggest you check out rxjava

Comment: *I will suggest you check out rxjava* 1) that completely beats the purpose of using livedata 2) the argument about bug fixed and maintenance doesn't hold much weight in this case considering the class is like 10 lines long

Comment: Isn't SingleLiveData an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 40):

> Is SingleLiveEvent actually part of the Android Architecture Components Library?

No, and it won't be: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122413110.
Basically, the official answer is *"Yes, regular livedata wasn't enough, so we introduced it in our examples but it's too hacky to be in the library"*.

Comment: Soo its too hacky but its the only way to provide single events back to the view. That soubds so depressing.

Comment: The absurdity of Android development in one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) for single UI events but it requires some hacking to use with Fragments to subscribe/unsubscribe automatically.