# ListView not rebuilding when returned to screen even after using setState()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that is populated based on number of files in a folder. On application start it manages to build my list correctly and as expected.

But on the new note screen the user has the option to save a note in this folder. When I come back to this screen the list does not rebuild based on this new file added. When I close application and restart, the file shows up in my list.

Following this answer: [is it possible to refresh or reload page with navigator.pop... like 1st (nav.push=>2) page to 2nd page and back from 2nd (nav.pop, value) to 1st page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769939/is-it-possible-to-refresh-or-reload-page-with-navigator-pop-like-1st-nav-pus) I used `.then()` with `Navigator.push` and rebuilt my list in `setState()` but it still does not update.

What am I doing wrong? Below is my code:

```
class _HomeListViewState extends State<HomeListView> {
  Directory easyDir;
  var txtList;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    easyDir = Directory(widget.folderPath);
    buildTxtList();
  }

  void buildTxtList(){
    //list of paths of my txt files in the folder
    txtList = easyDir
        .listSync()
        .map((item) => item.path)
        .where((item) => item.endsWith(".txt"))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(txtList.length);
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: txtList.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        File file = new File(txtList[index]);
        String name = file.path.split('/').last;
        return Card(
          color: (index % 2 == 0) ? Colors.grey.shade300 : Colors.white,
          shadowColor: Colors.teal,
          elevation: 7.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.assignment),
            title: Text(name),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoteEditScreen(
                  txtPath: file.path,
                ),
                ),
              ).then((value) {
                setState(() {
                  buildTxtList();
                });
              });
            },
            onLongPress: () => print('list tile long pressed'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by passing a function to *NoteEditScreen()* that will fire a callback in the main screen to rebuild it(We can already use the *buildTxtList* function or create a new one only for it)

```
void buildTxtList() {
    txtList = easyDir
        .listSync()
        .map((item) => item.path)
        .where((item) => item.endsWith(".txt"))
        .toList();
    
    setState(() {}); // To rebuild the Widget
   
  }
```

Then pass it down

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
                  NoteEditScreen(onPressed: buildTxtList),
                ),
                   );
```

Then in the *NoteEditScreen*, first declare the property, lastly, in the *AppBar* call it.

NOTE: You don't have to call the function in the *leading* property of the AppBar, you can maybe call it when they are done saving the note in the folder.

```
final Function onPressed;
  
  NoteEditScreen({this.onPressed});

  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Screen 2"),
       leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
         onPressed: () {
           onPressed();
           Navigator.pop(context);
         }
       )
     ),
```

NOTE: You should *definitely* take a look at these two posts that talk about using `setState(() {})`
[Empty set state what is the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383575/empty-set-state-what-is-the-point)

[Why does setState take a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379366/why-does-setstate-take-a-closure)