# how to refresh state on Navigator.Pop or Push in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, state-management

Here I have two pages first is called `BSP_signup_terms` page and the second is `Bsp_Service_page`. when I am on `BSP_signup_terms` on that page I have to select some checkbox based on the selected checkbox it will show me some data. but problem is that it will show me the complete data but when I get back to the `BSP_signup_terms`  from `Bsp_signup_page` and I am changing the checkbox and then again when I am pressing next button it will not change the result it same as the previous result.

Here is the Image of Output Page

*In this image I've attached both screen output when I am selecting only one checkbox it will render some value in service page and when I am back to the Terms and Condition page and select one more checkbox then it will not updating service page*

[image]

**Here is the code I've tried.**

---

**BSP_Signup_Terms_Page**

```
class BspLicensedSignupTermsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/bspLicensedSignupTerms";
  final BspSignupCommonModel bspSignupCommonModel;

  BspLicensedSignupTermsPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.bspSignupCommonModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BspLicensedSignupTermsPageState createState() =>
      _BspLicensedSignupTermsPageState();
}

class _BspLicensedSignupTermsPageState
    extends State<BspLicensedSignupTermsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _isWalkIn = false;
  bool _isHome = false;
  bool _isOnDemand = false;



  Widget _buildselectcheckbox() {
    return Text(
      AppConstantsValue.appConst['bsplicensedsignupterms']['selectcheck']
          ['translation'],
    );
  }

  // Walkin
  _onCustomerWalkin(value) {
    setState(() {
      _isWalkIn = value;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildCustomerWalkIn() {
    return TudoConditionWidget(
      text: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bsplicensedsignupterms']
          ['CustomerWalkIn']['translation'],
      onChanged: (value) {
        print(value);
        _onCustomerWalkin(value);
      },
      validate: false,
    );
  }


  // Home
  _onCustomerInHome(value) {
    setState(() {
      _isHome = value;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildCustomerInHome() {
    return TudoConditionWidget(
      text: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bsplicensedsignupterms']
          ['CustomerInHome']['translation'],
      onChanged: (value) {
        _onCustomerInHome(value);
      },
      validate: false,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCustomerInHomeHelp() {
    return Text(
      AppConstantsValue.appConst['bsplicensedsignupterms']['businesscheckhelp']
          ['translation'],
    );
  }

  // On Demand

  _onCustomerOnDemand(value) {
    setState(() {
      _isOnDemand = value;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildBusinessOnDemand() {
    return TudoConditionWidget(
      text: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bsplicensedsignupterms']
          ['BusinessOnDemand']['translation'],
      onChanged: (value) {
        _onCustomerOnDemand(value);
      },
      validate: false,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBusinessOnDemandHelp() {
    return Text(AppConstantsValue.appConst['bsplicensedsignupterms']
        ['businessprovidehelp']['translation']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text("Bsp Licensed Signup Terms and Condition"),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
        onPressed: () {
          NavigationHelper.navigatetoBack(context);
        },
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
    );

    final bottomNavigationBar = Container(
      height: 56,
      //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24, horizontal: 12),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            label: Text('Clear'),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _formKey.currentState.reset();
            },
          ),
          new FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight),
            label: Text('Next'),
            color: colorStyles["primary"],
            textColor: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                if (_isHome == false &&
                    _isOnDemand == false &&
                    _isWalkIn == false) {
                  showDialog(
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => ShowErrorDialog(
                            title: Text('Select Service'),
                            content: Text(
                              'Please select atleast one service type to proceed next',
                            ),
                          ));
                } else {
                  BspSignupCommonModel model = widget.bspSignupCommonModel;
                  model.isWalkin = _isWalkIn;
                  model.isHome = _isHome;
                  model.isOnDemand = _isOnDemand;
                  print(model.toJson());
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          BspServicePage(bspSignupCommonModel: model),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[

            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SafeArea(

                child: Form(
                  autovalidate: true,
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                      child: new Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                        child: new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            _buildselectcheckbox(),
                            _buildCustomerWalkIn(),
                            _buildCustomerInHome(),
                            _buildCustomerInHomeHelp(),
                            _buildBusinessOnDemand(),
                            _buildBusinessOnDemandHelp(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**BSP_Service_Page**

```
class BspServicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/bspService";
  final BspSignupCommonModel bspSignupCommonModel;

  BspServicePage({
    Key key,
    @required this.bspSignupCommonModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BspServicePageState createState() => _BspServicePageState();
}

class _BspServicePageState extends State<BspServicePage> {
  List<int> servicesIds = [];
  Map<String, bool> selection = {};
  List<BspServices.Service> selectedServices = [];
  SearchBarController _controller = new SearchBarController();
  String _searchText = '';
  bool refreshservices = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => ShowErrorDialog(
        title: Text('An Error Occurred!'),
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }

  void refresh() {
    setState(() {
      refreshservices = !refreshservices;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _bspServiceBloc = new BspServiceBloc();
    final appBar = SearchBar(
      controller: _controller,
      onQueryChanged: (String query) {
        print('Search Query $query');
        setState(() {
          _searchText = query;
        });
      },
      defaultBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            onPressed: () {
              refresh();
              NavigationHelper.navigatetoBack(context);
            }),
        title: Text('Select Services'),
      ),
    );

    final bottomNavigationBar = Container(
      height: 56,
      // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24, horizontal: 12),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            label: Text('Clear'),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print('reseting the state');
              setState(() {
                selection = {};
                servicesIds = [];
              });
            },
          ),
          new FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight),
            label: Text('Next'),
            color: colorStyles["primary"],
            textColor: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              BspSignupCommonModel model = widget.bspSignupCommonModel;
              model.servicesIds = servicesIds;
              model.services = selectedServices;
              print('servicesIds at the next button');
              print(servicesIds);
              print(model.toJson());
              if (servicesIds.length == 0) {
                _showErrorDialog(
                    'You need to select at least one service to proceed next!');
              } else {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => BusinessProfilePage(
                      bspSignupCommonModel: model,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      body: new BspServiceScreen(
        bspServiceBloc: _bspServiceBloc,
        bspSignupCommonModel: widget.bspSignupCommonModel,
        servicesIds: servicesIds,
        selection: selection,
        searchQuery: _searchText,
        selectedServices: selectedServices,
        refresh: refresh,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Bsp_service_screen**

```
class BspServiceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final BspServiceBloc _bspServiceBloc;
  final String searchQuery;
  final List<int> servicesIds;
  final Map<String, bool> selection;
  final BspSignupCommonModel bspSignupCommonModel;
  final List<BspServices.Service> selectedServices;
  final Function refresh;

  const BspServiceScreen({
    Key key,
    @required BspServiceBloc bspServiceBloc,
    @required this.bspSignupCommonModel,
    @required this.servicesIds,
    @required this.selection,
    @required this.selectedServices,
    @required this.refresh,
    this.searchQuery,
  })  : _bspServiceBloc = bspServiceBloc,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  BspServiceScreenState createState() {
    return new BspServiceScreenState(_bspServiceBloc);
  }
}

class BspServiceScreenState extends State<BspServiceScreen> {
  final BspServiceBloc _bspServiceBloc;

  BspServiceScreenState(this._bspServiceBloc);
  // Map<String, bool> _selection = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bool isHome = widget.bspSignupCommonModel.isHome;
    bool isWalkIn = widget.bspSignupCommonModel.isWalkin;
    bool isOnDemand = widget.bspSignupCommonModel.isOnDemand;
    this._bspServiceBloc.dispatch(LoadBspServiceEvent(
          countryId: 1,
          isHome: isHome,
          isOnDemand: isOnDemand,
          isWalkin: isWalkIn,
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<BspServiceBloc, BspServiceState>(
      bloc: widget._bspServiceBloc,
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        BspServiceState currentState,
      ) {
        if (currentState is UnBspServiceState) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (currentState is ErrorBspServiceState) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text(currentState.errorMessage ?? 'Error'),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (currentState is InBspServiceState) {
          // print(
          //     'in bsp service state, ${currentState.bspServices.servicesByCountry.length}');
          if (currentState.bspServices.servicesByCountry.length == 0) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("No Services available for this combination"),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return new Container(
              child:
                  _renderServices(currentState.bspServices.servicesByCountry),
            );
          }
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }

  List<ServicesByCountry> finalList = new List();

  ListView _renderServices(List<ServicesByCountry> lovCountryServices) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (widget.searchQuery != '') {
        finalList.clear();
        lovCountryServices.forEach((ServicesByCountry data) {
          if (data.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(widget.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
            setState(() {
              finalList.add(data);
            });
          } else {
            data.services.forEach((ServiceList.Service services) {
              if (services.name
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(widget.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
                setState(() {
                  finalList.add(data);
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          finalList.clear();
          finalList.addAll(lovCountryServices);
        });
      }
    });
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      itemCount: finalList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        ServicesByCountry item = finalList[index];
        List itemsList = item.services;
        return ExpansionTile(
          title: Text(item.name),
          children: List.generate(itemsList.length, (i) {
            widget.selection[itemsList[i].name] =
                widget.selection[itemsList[i].name] ?? itemsList[i].isSelected;
            return CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(itemsList[i].name),
              value: widget.selection[itemsList[i].name],
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.selection[itemsList[i].name] = val;
                  if (val) {
                    widget.servicesIds.add(itemsList[i].id);

                    List<BspServices.Service> services =
                        widget.selectedServices.where((service) {
                      return service.mainCategory == item.name;
                    }).toList();

                    SubCategory subService = new SubCategory(
                      id: itemsList[i].id,
                      name: itemsList[i].name,
                    );

                    List<SubCategory> subCategories = [];
                    if (services.length == 0) {
                      subCategories.add(subService);
                      widget.selectedServices.add(
                        new BspServices.Service(
                          mainCategory: item.name,
                          mainCategoryId: item.id,
                          subCategory: subCategories,
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      print('services in else');
                      print(services[0].subCategory);
                      subCategories = services[0].subCategory;
                      subCategories.add(subService);
                    }
                  } else {
                    widget.servicesIds.removeWhere((service) {
                      return service == itemsList[i].id;
                    });

                    List<BspServices.Service> services =
                        widget.selectedServices.where((service) {
                      return service.mainCategory == item.name;
                    }).toList();

                    services[0].subCategory.removeWhere((subService) {
                      return subService.id == itemsList[i].id;
                    });
                  }
                });
                print('widget.servicesIds after set state');
                print(widget.servicesIds);
              },
            );
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804891/force-flutter-navigator-to-reload-state-when-popping

Comment: Can you share the code of BspServiceScreen? That's where the problem actually is.

Comment: the question is updated. Please check it

Comment: the print(model.toJson()); before going to the Service page is printing the correct values but when you reach the Service page it shows another values?

Comment: yes right, it's printing correct value, but when i am trying to display it. it will give output only once

Comment: can you please help it @PabloBarrera

Comment: In the service page try create the service screen adding a key to it, like this new BspServiceScreen(key: ObjectKey(widget.bspSignupCommonModel), ...)

Comment: can you please explain it in as an answer

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem, did you try that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say for adding in the code.
Can you please tell me what i have to add exactly

Answer (score 30):

You can use setState() after return to the first page:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2())).then((value) {
  setState(() {
    // refresh state
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you just a little bit explain to me more, that where I've to use??

Comment: No, it's not working do you have any other solution?

Comment: Do try to use Navigator.pop() instead of NavigationHelper.navigatetoBack(context);

Comment: I misunderstanding that you want to refresh the first page after pop the second page but the thing you want is refresh the second page. When you push to new page, that page will rebuild state, so the reason of you is not about navigator but your code

Comment: I really want but I don't know what you do in the checkbox and what will be change to make second page to change. Just try something simple to test first

Comment: for the second page, I used the bloc for render service

Comment: @hoangquyy thanks man, a perfect answer to refresh list.

Comment: Use with `Navigator.pop(mContext, true)` ==> It's work for me,

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

First you add one method async method:-

```
void redirectToNextScreen() async {
    final Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => BspServicePage(bspSignupCommonModel: model));
    final result = await Navigator.push(mContext, route);
    try {
      if (result != null) {
        if (result) {
          //Return callback here.
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Then Next you can call this method in "**BSP_Signup_Terms_Page**" on **Next** button Pressed event.

Second you can add below line in "**BspServicePage**" screen **Next** and **Cancel** Events.

```
Navigator.pop(mContext, true); //true means refresh back page and false means not refresh.
```

Comment: No, buddy, it's not working. my service page bloc is still not refreshing. when i am restart the it's only refresh