# validation is becomes true before validation is checked in flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a question about validation. My widget field validation is become true before checked. when I am just open this page validation is automatically becomes true.

I want that validation after user input. but this validation is becoming true before the user entering something inside from the field. so can anyone help me? your help will be appreciated.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
class BspSignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/bspSignup";

  @override
  _BspSignupPageState createState() => _BspSignupPageState();
}

class _BspSignupPageState extends State<BspSignupPage>
    with AfterLayoutMixin<BspSignupPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // final TextEditingController _bspPhone = TextEditingController();
  final MaskedTextController _bspPhone =
      new MaskedTextController(mask: '(000)-000-0000');
  final TextEditingController _bspBusinessName = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bspBusinessLegalAddress =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bspBusinessLicense = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bspLicenseAuthority = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bspEstYear = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bspNumberOfEmployee = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bspBusinessDetailsComment =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _countryCodeController =
      new TextEditingController();

  BSPSignupRepository _bspSignupRepository = new BSPSignupRepository();
  bool bspcheck = false;
  BspSignupCommonModel model = BspSignupCommonModel();
  int radioValue = -1;
  String _alternatephone;
  String _businessname;
  bool addressenabled = false;
  List<dynamic> _type = <dynamic>[];
  Map<String, dynamic> _typeValue;
  String _establishyear;
  String _numberofemployee;
  LocationResult _pickedLocation;
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  bool flexibletime = false;
  DateTime date;
  TimeOfDay time;
  Map<String, dynamic> bspsignupdata = new Map<String, dynamic>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(model);
    _bspNumberOfEmployee.text = "1";
    _bspSignupRepository.getBSTypes().then((businessTypeResponse) {
      print('businessTypeResponse');
      print(businessTypeResponse);
      if (businessTypeResponse['error'] != null) {
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _type = businessTypeResponse['data']['businessTypes'];
        });
      }
    });
    setState(() {
      date = new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(hours: 1));
      time = new TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(date);
    });
  }

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    model = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    if (model == null) {
      model = new BspSignupCommonModel();
    } else {
      print('model for edit');
      _setExistingDetails(model);
    }
  }

  void _setExistingDetails(bspModel) {
    _bspBusinessName.text = bspModel.businessLegalName;
    _bspPhone.text = model.businessPhoneNumber;
    _bspEstYear.text = model.businessYear;
    _bspNumberOfEmployee.text = model.numberofEmployees;
    _bspBusinessLegalAddress.text = model.businessLegalAddress;
    _typeValue = model.businessTypes;

  }

  Widget _buildlegalbusinessname() {
    return new TudoTextWidget(
      controller: _bspBusinessName,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.business),
      labelText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['legalbusinessname']
          ['translation'],
      hintText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['legalbusinessname']
          ['translation'],
      validator: (val) =>
          Validators.validateRequired(val, "Business legal name"),
      onSaved: (val) {
        _businessname = val;
        bspsignupdata['businessname'] = _businessname;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildalternatephone() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new TudoTextWidget(
            controller: _countryCodeController,
            enabled: false,
            prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.globe),
            labelText: "code",
            hintText: "Country Code",
          ),
          flex: 2,
        ),
        new SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        new Expanded(
          child: new TudoNumberWidget(
            controller: _bspPhone,
            validator: Validators().validateMobile,
            labelText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['alternatephone']
                ['translation'],
            hintText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['alternatephone']
                ['translation'],
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone),
            onSaved: (val) {
              _alternatephone = val;
              bspsignupdata['alternatephone'] = _alternatephone;
            },
          ),
          flex: 5,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildestablishedyear() {
    return new TudoNumberWidget(
      controller: _bspEstYear,
      prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar),
      labelText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['establishedyear']
          ['translation'],
      hintText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['establishedyear']
          ['translation'],
      validator: Validators().validateestablishedyear,
      maxLength: 4,
      onSaved: (val) {
        _establishyear = val.trim();
        bspsignupdata['establishyear'] = _establishyear;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildnumberofemployees() {
    return new TudoNumberWidget(
      controller: _bspNumberOfEmployee,
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.control_point_duplicate),
      labelText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['numberofemployees']
          ['translation'],
      hintText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['numberofemployees']
          ['translation'],
      validator: Validators().validatenumberofemployee,
      onSaved: (val) {
        _numberofemployee = val.trim();
        bspsignupdata['numberofemployes'] = _numberofemployee;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildbusinesslegaladdress() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new TudoTextWidget(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.business),
            labelText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']
                ['businesslegaladdress']['translation'],
            hintText: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']
                ['businesslegaladdress']['translation'],
            controller: _bspBusinessLegalAddress,
            enabled: addressenabled,
            validator: (val) =>
                Validators.validateRequired(val, "Business legal name"),
          ),
          flex: 5,
        ),
        new SizedBox(
          width: 10.0,
        ),
        new Expanded(
          child: new FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: colorStyles['primary'],
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.globe,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            elevation: 0,
            onPressed: () async {
              LocationResult result = await LocationPicker.pickLocation(
                context,
                "AIzaSyDZZeGlIGUIPs4o8ahJE_yq6pJv3GhbKQ8",
              );
              print("result = $result");
              setState(() {
                _pickedLocation = result;
                addressenabled = !addressenabled;
              });
              // setState(() => _pickedLocation = result);
              _bspBusinessLegalAddress.text = _pickedLocation.address;
              model.businessGeoLocation = new BusinessGeoLocation(
                lat: _pickedLocation.latLng.latitude.toString(),
                lng: _pickedLocation.latLng.longitude.toString(),
              );
            },
          ),
          flex: 2,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildbusinesstype() {
    return FormBuilder(
      autovalidate: true,
      child: FormBuilderCustomField(
          attribute: "Business type",
          validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
          formField: FormField(
            builder: (FormFieldState<dynamic> field) {
              return InputDecorator(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                  labelText: _type == []
                      ? 'Select Personal Identification type'
                      : 'Business type',
                  hintText: "Select Personal Identification type",
                  errorText: field.errorText,
                ),
                isEmpty: _typeValue == [],
                child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: new DropdownButton(
                    // isExpanded: true,
                    hint: Text("Select Personal Identification type"),
                    value: _typeValue,
                    isDense: true,
                    onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
                      print('newValue');
                      print(newValue);
                      setState(() {
                        _typeValue = newValue;
                        field.didChange(newValue);
                      });
                    },
                    items: _type.map(
                      (dynamic value) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value['name']),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildlegalbusinesscheck() {
    return TudoConditionWidget(
      text: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['legalbusinesscheck']
          ['translation'],
      errortext: AppConstantsValue.appConst['bspSignup']['errortext']
          ['translation'],
    );
  }

  Widget content(BuildContext context, BspSignupViewModel bspSignupVm) {
    final appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text("BSP Signup"),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
        onPressed: () {
          NavigationHelper.navigatetoBack(context);
        },
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
    );

    final bottomNavigationBar = Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      height: 56,

      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            label: Text('Clear'),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _formKey.currentState.reset();
              _bspPhone.clear();
              _bspBusinessName.clear();
              _bspBusinessLicense.clear();
              _bspLicenseAuthority.clear();
              _bspEstYear.clear();
              _bspNumberOfEmployee.clear();
              _bspBusinessDetailsComment.clear();
              _bspBusinessLegalAddress.clear();
            },
          ),
          new FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight),
            label: Text('Next'),
            color: colorStyles["primary"],
            textColor: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                model.businessLegalName = _bspBusinessName.text;
                model.businessPhoneNumber = _bspPhone.text;
                model.businessYear = _bspEstYear.text;
                model.numberofEmployees = _bspNumberOfEmployee.text;
                model.businessType = _typeValue['id'];
                model.businessLegalAddress = _bspBusinessLegalAddress.text;
                model.businessTypes = _typeValue;
                print('model');
                print(model.licensed);
                if (_typeValue['name'].toLowerCase() ==
                    "Licensed / Registered".toLowerCase()) {
                  model.isLicensed = true;
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BspLicensedSignupPage(
                        bspSignupCommonModel: model,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  model.isLicensed = false;
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BspUnlicensedSignupPage(
                        bspSignupCommonModel: model,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Form(
          autovalidate: true,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Background(),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: new Container(
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      _buildlegalbusinessname(),
                      _buildalternatephone(),
                      _buildestablishedyear(),
                      _buildnumberofemployees(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      _buildbusinesslegaladdress(),
                      _buildbusinesstype(),
                      _buildlegalbusinesscheck(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StoreConnector<AppState, BspSignupViewModel>(
      converter: (Store<AppState> store) => BspSignupViewModel.fromStore(store),
      onInit: (Store<AppState> store) {
        _countryCodeController.text =
            store.state.auth.loginUser.user.country.isdCode;
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context, BspSignupViewModel bspSignupVm) =>
          content(context, bspSignupVm),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your widget field validation is become true before checked becuase you have given static flag true to "autovalidate" to solve this issue you have to manage flag variable for that

Example:-

```
bool _autoValidate = false;


Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidate: _autoValidate,
      child: Container(child:Text("")));
```

And change flag value when first time validating form

```
void _buttonClicked(BuildContext context) {
  setState(() {
    _autoValidate = true;
    });
  }
```

**Update:-**

**autovalidate** is deprecated from Flutter v1.19

Replace **autovalidate** with autovalidateMode.**autovalidateMode** can have one of the below 3 values:

**autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled:** No auto validation will occur.

**autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always:** Used to auto-validate FormField even without user interaction.

**autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction:** Used to auto-validate FormField only after each user interaction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388309/how-to-refresh-state-on-navigator-pop-or-push-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment103124082_58388309

can you please try your hands on this question
it will make my day