# Flutter: CupertinoTabScaffold tab content does not refresh after closing PageRoute

Tags: flutter, dart

**Problem**: CupertinoTabScaffold tab content does not refresh after closing new screen from CupertinoPageRoute

**App**:
There is a list of data in a Listview.
I open one data set and remove the favourite status (checked=false).
I close the data set and the listview should refresh (FutureBuilder to an SQL database).

**Details**:
I've got a Flutter App with two layouts (Material and Cupertino).
In each layout i have four tabs and the content widgets are the same.
On the Cupertino App every tab consists of a CupertinoPageScaffold.
When i press on an element it navigates to a new screen with CupertinoPageRoute.
After closing the CupertinoPageRoute the tab content is not refreshing.
The tab content is refreshing when i switch between the four tabs.

If one CupertinoPageRoute is open and i open a new one from here and close it again
then the content of the opened CupertinoPageScaffold is refreshing.
The data is refreshing without a callback etc., just by calling the future (i think).

Means there should be a problem with the CupertinoTabScaffold.
There is no problem on the Material App.
The tab contents of the Material App are refreshing when closing a MaterialPageRoute.

**Question**:
Is there a problem at this position?
Do you have the same issue or maybe a solution or workaround?

**Code**:
My code is not really representative so i will create a new clean project for you.
please confirm if code is necessary.

**What i tried**:
I tried a lot of solutions from the internet like callbacks, setState, .then, .whencomplete for the route.
nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 03.10.2021**: the tabcontroller with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin reloads the open tab when i open or close an new screen. if i just use DefaultTabController Widget than it doesn't. So i have to edit the CupertinoTabController.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin  {
  late TabController _tabController;
  final CupertinoTabController _cuptabController = CupertinoTabController();

  Future<void> _refreshdata() async {
    downloadJSON1();
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  callback() {
    _refreshdata();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _refreshdata();
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2, initialIndex: 0);
    _cuptabController.index = widget.starttab;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for the moment i solved it with a .then-callback from PageRoute. i just passed the callback to the deepest Widget/PageRoute. But if you have a solution/idea for the tabcontroller would be great.

Souce:
[how to refresh state on Navigator.Pop or Push in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388309/how-to-refresh-state-on-navigator-pop-or-push-in-flutter)

```
      Navigator.push(context,
      CupertinoPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => MyWidget(
          'myparameters'),),).then((value) => setState(() {callback();}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a few options:

**Option 1:**
change your `FutureBuilder` into a `StreamBuilder`.
`FutureBuilder` does not refresh automatically when you save the data which `StreamBuilder` does very well.

**Option 2:**
Use a `setState` but not on the context of the route you are closing, but rather on the context of the original page you want to refreh

```
setState(() {  });
```

Comment: same behavior as before; means no refresh

Comment: i am developing two small dummy apps with saving and showing favorite dataset, one app with material and one with cupertino layout. a live example should be better to test and analyze with. i will try uploading a gif/video of app behavior, too.

Comment: Did you try to change FutureBuilder into StreamBuiler? It must work and it is a quick change

Comment: Yes i changed it into Streambuilder, it works like before on Android, but no improvement on CupertinoApp. At the moment i'm dev a new empty app, but it doesn't seem to work on android too. :-)  - I have to recreate it.