# When to use Provider.of<X> vs. Consumer<X> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm still wrapping my head around state-management techniques in flutter and am a bit confused about when and why to use `Provider.of<X>` vs. `Consumer<X>`. I  understand (I think) from the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) that when choosing between these two you would use Provider.of when we want access to the data, but you don't need the UI to change. So the following (taken from the docs) gets access to the data and updates the UI on new events:

```
return HumongousWidget(
  // ...
  child: AnotherMonstrousWidget(// <- This widget will rebuild on new data events
    // ...
    child: Consumer<CartModel>(
      builder: (context, cart, child) {
        return Text('Total price: ${cart.totalPrice}');
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Whereas, where we only need the data on don't want to rebuild with UI, we'd use `Provider.of<X>` with the `listen` parameter set to `false`, as below:

```
Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false).add(item); \\Widget won't rebuild
```

However, `listen` isn't required and so the following will run too:

```
Provider.of<CartModel>(context).add(item); \\listener optional
```

So this brings me to a few questions:

1. Is this the correct way to distinguish `Provider.of<X>` and `Consumer<X>`. Former doesn't update UI, latter does?
2. If `listen` isn't set to `false` will the widget be rebuilt by default or not rebuilt? What if `listen` is set to `true`?
3. Why have `Provider.of` with the option to rebuild the UI at all when we have `Consumer`?

Comment: I'm just adding to this:

context.watch<CartModel>()
is another way to access data from a provider, this^ line is equivalent to:
Provider.of<CartModel>(context)

while

context.read<CartModel>()
is another way to access data from a provider, this^ line is equivalent to:
Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false)

Comment: The fact that there are at least three different APIs for this same functionality: Provider.of  context.watch and Consumer, not to mention ValueListenable and the rest, makes for a lot to wrap one's head around. I sympathize with the OP. What saved  me is the "Your First Flutter App" codelab, that teaches this with context.watch. I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

It doesn't matter. But to explain things rapidly:

`Provider.of` is the **only** way to obtain and listen to an object.
`Consumer`, `Selector`, and all the *ProxyProvider calls `Provider.of` to work.

`Provider.of` vs `Consumer` is a matter of personal preference. But there's a few arguments for both

#### Provider.of

- can be called in all the widgets lifecycle, including click handlers and `didChangeDependencies`
- doesn't increase the indentation

#### Consumer

- allows more granular widgets rebuilds
- solves most BuildContext misuse

Comment: This is helpful. I'm going to accept this response, especially for others. But can you point to a reference for this statement: "Provider.of is the only way to obtain and listen to an object. Consumer, Selector, and all the *ProxyProvider calls Provider.of to work." This isn't something I've seen in the docs and it really helped me!

Comment: This is just an implementation detail of how Consumer/... works. Here's the [source](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/packages/provider/lib/src/consumer.dart). You can see that `Consumer` is basically nothing but `Provider.of` in a new widget

Comment: Are there any resources about learning to prevent BuildContext misuse?

Comment: @RémiRousselet link doesn't work anymore. Working link is: [source](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/lib/src/consumer.dart)

Comment: In a word;
`Comsumer` uses `Provider.of` in fact but it has a builder which rebuild it's child widget.

Comment: what about ```context.watch``` & ```context.read``` ??

Comment: @Panagiss - see the comment in under the original question by @Cedric - it explains `context.watch` and `context.read` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774301/when-to-use-provider-ofx-vs-consumerx-in-flutter#comment127381229_58774301

Answer (score 36):

### Provider.of<>

applying provider, whole widget will rebuild if listen true.

### Consumer<>

using consumer only specifically allowed widget will rebuild.

Comment: What if we use provider.of listen true within consumer?

Answer (score 20):

For your questions:

1. Is this the correct way to distinguish `Provider.of<X>` and `Consumer<X>`. Former doesn't update UI, latter does?

`Provider.of<X>` depends on value of `listen` to trigger a new `State.build` to widgets and `State.didChangeDependencies` for `StatefulWidget`.

`Consumer<X>` always update UI, as it uses `Provider.of<T>(context)`, where `listen` is `true`. See full source [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/lib/src/consumer.dart).

2. If `listen` isn't set to `false` will the widget be rebuilt by default or not rebuilt? What if `listen` is set to `true`?

Default value is `true`, means will trigger a new `State.build` to widgets and `State.didChangeDependencies` for `StatefulWidget`. See full source [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/lib/src/consumer.dart).

`static T of<T>(BuildContext context, {bool listen = true})`.

3. Why have `Provider.of` with the option to rebuild the UI at all when we have `Consumer`?

Pretty much covered by Rémi Rousselet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774889/418439).

Answer (score 15):

There should not be any performance concern by using it, moreover, we should use consumers if we want to change some specific widget only on screen. This is the best approach I can say in terms of coding practice.

```
 return Container(
    // ...
    child: Consumer<PersonModel>(
      builder: (context, person, child) {
        return Text('Name: ${person.name}');
      },
    ),
  );
```

Like in the above example, we are only required to update the value of the Single Text Widget so add consumers there instead of Provider which is accessible to other widgets as well.

**Note:** Consumer or Provider update the only reference of your instance which widgets are using, if some widgets are not using then it will not re-drawn.

Answer (score 7):

The widget `Consumer` doesn't do any fancy work. It just calls `Provider.of` in a new widget, and delegate its build implementation to [builder].
It's just syntactic sugar for `Provider.of` but the funny thing is I think `Provider.of` is simpler to use.

Look at this article for more clearance 
https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-tutorial-provider/

Answer (score 7):

We have 3 things to understand here.

> When you wrap Provider around a widget it sets up a reference to a widget tree and a variable whose changes you want to refer to.

using Provider.of(context) you can get access to the variable you want to monitor and make changes in it.

> Provider.of(context) with and without listen gives you a reference to the above-declared Provider object and a widget tree where it can be accessed from. But as said by others, it rebuild the whole widget tree it sits on top of when listen is not false.

In the end, you can use consumer to monitor any changes that happened using the above step

> The consumer acts like a more granular listener and be applied to a fixed widget to help avoid unnecessary rebuilds.

Answer (score 2):

it's just a personal preference and depends on how you understand and use provider.
so the way i think of provider is it's just an object that is providing a ChangeNotifier Object that has **Code** and **Data** down the widget Tree.

So,I use :

#### Consumer<T>

When i want to listen to changes in **Data** and update/rebuild my UI according to those changes.

#### Provider.of<T>

When i just want to call the **Code**. with the listen parameter set to false.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is to know what the difference is, here is a track

**Consumer**

reload consumer-only child widgets

**Provider.of** (with listen true)

reload from the last buildcontext found in the tree

actually in a simple example

[exemple1 provider.of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIG2t.png)

in exemple1 when I click on my container, his increase his size ( gesturedetector send a newvalue at h variable , h variable is in function named method in provider)

with 'provider.of' flutter rebuild at the first Buildcontext below @override

that mean the totality of tree are rebuild

[exemple2 consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amryr.png)

in exemple2 when I click on my container, his increase his size ( gesturedetector send a newvalue at h variable , h variable is in function named method in provider)but with consumer only sélectionned widget are rebuild

that mean one widget are rebuild the other widget doesn't "move"

I hope I could help you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to rebuild the widget or get the value.

1. Provider.of(context) or context.read()

   - `context.read<TestProvider>()` returns the Model without listening for changes.
   - `context.watch<TestProvider>()` makes the widget listen for changes on the Model.
   - `Provider.of<TestProvider>(context, listen: false)` works the same as `context.read<TestProvider>()`.
   - `Provider.of<TestProvider>(context)` works the same as `context.watch<TestProvider>()`.
2. Using Consumer for Specific Widget Rebuilds:

   - Certain widgets can be built without rebuilding the whole content using `Consumer`.
   - allows more granular widgets rebuilds
   - solves most `BuildContext` misuse

If it's helpful to you, then accept the answer and don't forget to upvote.