# Could not find the correct Provider inconsistent behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Hi I'm new to Flutter and Provider and can't make sense of this error. Basically I'm using `MultiProvider` to manage the states like below, and this works really great for one of them (Auth) but not other(User) even though I'm using them in the same way.
I get this error.

`Note there are actually more providers, but simplified it for sake of simpler code example`

#### Error

```sh
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building StartPage(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Auth>, _InheritedProviderScope<UserLocation>, _InheritedProviderScope<UserState>, _InheritedProviderScope<BottomNavigationBarProvider>]):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this StartPage Widget

To fix, please:

  * Ensure the Provider<User> is an ancestor to this StartPage Widget
  * Provide types to Provider<User>
  * Provide types to Consumer<User>
  * Provide types to Provider.of<User>()
  * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
```

#### Main.dart

```dart
class SchoolApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Auth()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => User()),
          ],
          child: HomePage(),
        ));
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserState _userState = Provider.of<UserState>(context);
    switch (_userState.status) {
      case UserStatus.UnAuthenticated:
        return LoginScreen();
      case UserStatus.Authenticated:
        return StartPage();
    }
  }
}
```

#### StartPage.dart

```dart
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget with ChangeNotifier {

  Timer timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context);
    final _user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: true);
...
```

#### User.dart

```dart
class User extends ChangeNotifier{
  Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

  String _userId, _firstName, _lastName, _school, _email, _description, _employer, _title, _name;
  List<String> _ideologies, _interests, _religions;
  UserType _userType;
...
```

#### Auth.dart

```dart
class Auth extends ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final AuthResult authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    notifyListeners();
    return authResult.user.uid.toString();
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question for visibility. So found the answer to my question here. https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/422#issuecomment-632030627

Basically I imported the package in the wrong way, I did
import 'path/file.dart'

Instead of specifying the full path 
import 'package:/path/file.dart'

Answer (score 1):

```
class SchoolApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
         ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(create: (_) => Auth()),
         ChangeNotifierProvider<User>(create: (_) => User()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
        ));
  } 
}
```

Wrap your MaterialApp with MultiProvider. *I might have made some bracket issue in my code above*

Comment: This doesn't work either, I'm getting the same error, but in any case I shouldn't have to put it above my MaterialApp either since ideally you'd want to put it as far down the three as possible, right?

Comment: Ohh my bad I didn't saw that you aren't defining type ChangeNotifierProvider, you can see changes in my original answer. Tell me if it still shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap with Consumer the widget that requires to get date from provider:

```
  Foo(
  child: Consumer<Auth, User>(
    builder: (context, auth, user, child) {
      return YourWidget(a: yourProviderData, child: child);
    },
    child: Baz(),
  ),
)
```

You can try also wrap your code with the widget `Builder(builder: (context) => )`, to have access to the nearest context reference.

Comment: This didn't really work for me, same error. If I understand correctly from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774301/when-to-use-provider-ofx-vs-consumerx-in-flutter consumer uses provider.of under the hood