# ConnectionState always waiting

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

Why `connectionState` is always in **waiting** when it is back from **pageB** ???

**Page A**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        _bloc.getList(context);  
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: WillPopScope(
          child: RefreshIndicator(
              key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
              onRefresh: _refresh,
              child: Container(
                  child: StreamBuilder<List<ABC>>(
                      stream: _bloc.abcStream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return Center(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/loading.gif',
                                width: 200.0,
                                height: 200.0,
                              ),
                            );
                            break;

                          case ConnectionState.active:
                            if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
                              return Container(
                                child: Text('empty'),
                              );
                            } else {
                              return ListView.builder(
                                 .......
                            }
                            break;
                          default:
                            return Text("Error");
                        }
                      }))),
          onWillPop: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            elevation: 0.0,
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
               Navigator.pushNamed(context, PageB.ROUTE).then((onValue) async{
                 _bloc.getList(context);   // call this function once it is back from pageB
                setState(() {});
              });
            }));
  }
```

When page A is first loaded, it will call initState, and list is successfully populated to listView. But if I click the floating action button to go to page B, then click back ( `Navigator.pop(context, true);`), the list doesn't populated to listView. It always in waiting(Keeps display loading.gif).

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: Well it's hard to tell what's going on here without a bit more of the code you're using - have you verified that A) _bloc.getList(context) is actually being called after the navigator is pushed; that B) the streambuilder is actually being called, and that C)
 that the list instance returned from the stream is a different list, even if it's just a straight copy of the last one - if it is the same object, it is conceivable that it might not trigger the rebuild of the ListView properly. But a minimal code example would be much more helpful.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie I have fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I solved.

Add `listen : false` in `didChangeDependencies`.

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _bloc = Provider.of<Bloc>(context, listen: false);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to setState if you are updating the stream itself.

Comment: so the solution is ?