# Wait for pop from grandchild when using pushReplacment

Tags: flutter

First off, I have code like this:

```
// Assume First, Second, and Third exist.

class FirstState extends State<First> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getMenuButton(
        onPressed: () async => {
                await Navigator.push(
                context,
                CustomMaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Second()),
                ),
                print("Back to first"),
            });
  }
}

class SecondState extends State<Second> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getMenuButton(
        onPressed: () async => {
                await Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                CustomMaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Third()),
                ),                
            });
  }
}

class ThirdState extends State<Third> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getMenuButton(
        onPressed: () async => {
                await Navigator.pop()
            });
  }
}
```

Note that First does `push`, Second does `pushReplacement`, and Third does `pop`.

What happens:

1. Press button on First.
2. Press button on Second.
3. You see "Back to First".

What I want to happen:

1. Press button on First.
2. Press button on Second.
3. Press button on Third.
4. You see "Back to First".

In short, the problem is `pushReplacement` causes the `await Navigator.push` in First to return immediately ([as per the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html)), whereas I want it to work as if I just did `push`, where it will keep waiting until it pops.

The reason I want this is because I want to pass data back from Third to First, but if I use pushReplacement I cannot do this. As a workaround, I would like to await the push in First and then reload some data in First, but I cannot find a way to make First wait for Third to pop.

Perhaps if I could control what `pushReplacement` returns, I could make it return a key to Third and then await that? This seems pretty janky though.

tl;dr: How do I wait for a child navigation route when I use `pushReplacement` in the child, breaking the "await connection" from parent to grandchild.

This question is similar to [Force Flutter navigator to reload state when popping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804891/force-flutter-navigator-to-reload-state-when-popping?rq=1), but none of the solutions there work here because of the `pushReplacement` (which is a hard requirement here).

Thanks!