# Reload previous page when Navigator.of().pop() called in next page

Tags: flutter, dart

This is code to show next page from profile page. In this edit page, there are several buttons to edit user information.
When users finished to edit, Navigator.of(context).pop() called and profile page appears again.

In profile page:

```
String userName = "none"; // public string
........
Text(userName),
IconButton(icon: Icons.edit, onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/edit"))
```

In edit page:

```
IconButton(icon: Icons.edit, onPressed: () => username = "ABCD")
```

and when user finished editing, push a back button in appbar. this button is standard of Navigator not unique widget.

---

These code can't change `Text(userName)` when back from edit page, just show old string.

So how can I call this profile page again? Or reload only `userName` string?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806432/9739475 it has multiple solutions to a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state management package like `RiverPod` and update the specific widget. Update that specific widget by using `Scoped Provider` and listening to that specific value.

[More about RiverPod](http://riverpod.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

As Yash presented, it worked with `.then((value) => setState(() {}))`.

profile page:

```
String userName = "none";
.....
Text(userName),
IconButton(icon: Icons.edit, onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/edit").then((value) => setState(() {})))
```

edit page:

```
setState( () { userName = "ABCDEFG"; })
```